# Detect contention in libevent

Tags: monitoring, health-check, libevent, contention

I want to setup monitoring in my `libevent` based program to detect the situation when the system becomes overloaded and there is a contention or queue buildup. So far I found `event_base_get_num_events` as a proxy of the pending event queue length; the other metric I am using is CPU load as reported by `rusage`.

Are there any libevent specific metrics that could be exposed?